# How can I get my LaTeX set up on Emacs/AUCTeX to use the -file-line-error option when calling pdfTeX

Tags: pdftex, miktex, emacs, auctex

I have been puzzling over this for the past few hours and can't quite figure it out.  I am using AUCTeX 11.87 and MiKTeX 2.9 on Emacs 24.2 (obtained from Vincent Goulet with AUCTeX pre-packaged):

I am having trouble getting AUCTeX to compile my LaTeX file on windows 7 and throws me into a blank screen with a cryptic message of 'Error after last TeX file closed".  Even though same file compiles on my set-up on Ubuntu 12.1.  From my searching this site and Google I seem to have tracked the problem to the need to use the -file-line-error flag when pdfTeX gets called.  I read through the code for AUCTeX but it gets very convoluted and I can't figure out where I would need to insert -file-line-error in any of the customizable options.

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be welcome. 
I would prefer not to manually change any configuration files as I came across an admonishment not to do so in the pdfTeX manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is `M-x customize-variable RET LaTeX-command RET`, then add `-file-line-error` to the command, and Save for Future Sessions.  You may also have to do the same for other engines e.g. by customizing `TeX-command`.  You can have more control over which engines you want to use by customizing the `TeX-engine-alist`.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of auctex, it looks like it'll be more reliable to set `TeX-command-extra-options`, which is designed for just this purpose, and doesn't make you override the various forms of `TeX-command`.  So this is a nice, non-destructive way of adding options without interfering with changes down the line -- like switching between TeX flavors, enabling synctex, etc.

As I understand it (might be wrong about this), the value can't be set globally, but must be set for each file.  You can do this with a hook.  I have the following in my `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq TeX-command-extra-options "-file-line-error -shell-escape")
  )
)
```

[Also note that `synctex` can now be turned on with `(setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)`, rather than being included in the command line.  This can be set globally, so it should go outside that hook.]

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions on how to proceed would be welcome. I would prefer not to manually change any configuration files as I came across an admonishment not to do so in the pdfTeX manual.

I never bothered to repair this kind of misbehaviour of Emacs, because if I encounter "TeX exited abnormally", I have a quick look at the output. You get it in a fraction of a second with "C-c C-l". Change into this buffer: "C-x o" and search for the *first* error.